# Maximum run of heads in n coin tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we do 6 coin tosses and we wanna know probability of maximum runs for each number of "k" consecutive heads.

For example HHHTHH counts as 3, HTTHTH counts as 1 and HHTTHH counts as 2. I've written a python script that goes through all 2^6 possibilities and calculates the probability. The way I do it in my script is that I check each possibility, for example HHHTTT and counts the max() number of "H" letter in that string.

This is a sample output for 6 coin tosses:

Max number of 0 Heads in row is  1

Probability:  1.5625 %

Max number of 1 Heads in row is  20

Probability:  31.25 %

Max number of 2 Heads in row is  23

Probability:  35.9375 %

Max number of 3 Heads in row is  12

Probability:  18.75 %

Max number of 4 Heads in row is  5

Probability:  7.8125 %

Max number of 5 Heads in row is  2

Probability:  3.125 %

Max number of 6 Heads in row is  1

Probability:  1.5625 %

My problem is that I need to derive a general result/formula that works for any number of coins "n" and maximum run length "k".

Comment: Well, recursively if your string begins $H^aT$ then you are down to looking at strings of length $n-(a+1)$ (assuming $a<k$, of course.  if $a≥k$ then the probability is $1$). If you are automating the process, this might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_n$ be the length of the longest run of heads in a sequence of $n$ coin flips. Then

> $$
> P(L_n\ge m)=\sum_{r=1}^{n-m+1}(-1)^{r+1}\left[\binom{n-rm}{r}+2\binom{n-rm}{r-1}\right]\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{r(m+1)}
> $$

You were asking about $P(L_n=k)$. To find this, use the above formula, and $P(L_n=k)=P(L_n\ge k)-P(L_n>k+1)$.

If you don't want to deal with the above summation, there is a recursive way to compute $P(L_n\ge m)$, which I will denote as $p_{n}$. By conditioning on the last $m$ flips, we have

> $$
> p_n = (1/2)^m + (1/2)p_{n-1}+(1/2)^2p_{n-2}+\dots+(1/2)^{m}p_{n-m}
> $$

Both quoted formulae are from Sheldon Ross, *A First Course in Probability, 9th Edition*, p. 154.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please show how the calculation would look like for the recursive method? For example max number of 2 heads in row in 6 tosses. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: You may be interested in this OEIS entry: http://oeis.org/A048004